# Generar un loop para la consulta de datos en android a través de una base de datos

Tags: android, json

Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en Android, la duda es la siguiente:

Tengo un XML donde muestro los datos que estoy recibiendo de una consulta a través de un web service. Siendo especifico, estoy utilizando una base de datos MySQL y utilizando PHP para generar la consulta.

Tengo un botón con el cual genero la consulta a través de un campo de la base de datos que le paso a la aplicación como parámetro de consulta.

La consulta funciona bien, me devuelve los datos y los asigna a los diferentes `TextView` que tengo en la interfaz de la aplicación.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es que la aplicación genere una consulta de manera constante y que me devuelva los datos nuevos que voy ingresando a la base de datos, ya que al oprimir el botón dicha consulta sólo la genera una vez.

¿Alguien me podría indicar cómo generar un ciclo infinito para que se repita el código y se vayan actualizando los valores de los `TextView`? Me gustaría que sólo sea oprimiendo una vez el botón, una especie de loop a partir de oprimir el botón.

Este es parte de mi código:

```
    btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new datosInvitado.ConsultarDatos().execute("http://187.155.10.94/Android/consultaultimodato.php?Chipid="+Chipid.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private class ConsultarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        JSONArray ja = null;
        try {
            ja = new JSONArray(result);
            Ritmo.setText(ja.getString(0));
            Temperatura.setText(ja.getString(1));
            Tiempo.setText(ja.getString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    Log.i("URL",""+myurl);
    myurl = myurl.replace(" ","%20");
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("respuesta", "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: si lo único que quieres es hacer un ciclo infinito puedes hacerlo con while(true), si quieres algo más deberías rehacer la pregunta y poner algo de código para entender mejor lo que quieres. Pasa por [tour] y por [ask] para que conozcas como funciona el sitio y como realizar preguntas de calidad.

Comment: La idea que tengo en mente es que al oprimir ese botón se genere el loop.

Comment: @Angelc , ¿tu idea es que se repita la consulta X segundos después de haber recibido la respuesta anterior o con una frecuencia de X segundos independientemente de si la consulta anterior fue contestada por el servidor o no?

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias ya esta.